# Split data of one column

Tags: mysql

Hello  i had one column  with  three  set of datas.

```
    email ; contact ; box 
      Alfreds Feutterkist feutterkist@gmail.com kaiba corp
```

I tried to do it using exel i  had data all  over the place since the format is too messy. ( exported from streak)

How do i split those three strings into single columns ?

I tried to do it using exel i  had data all  over the place since the format is too messy. ( exported from streak)

How do i split those three strings into single columns ?

I use mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have considered the sequence of the column are fixed, I have considered that email column has your string.

Based on that you may use below query

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS field_name_1,
    TRIM( SUBSTR(email, LOCATE(' ', email)) ) AS field_name_2
FROM table_name
```